# Jquery: if mouseleave = true then DO THIS

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, mouseleave

Simple question, how would I accomplish this functionality in Jquery:
Test whether the mouse is hovering over `.myBox`

```
    if ($(".myBox").mouseleave = true) {
        DO SOMETHING
    } else {something else}
```

OR

```
    if ($(".myBox").mouseover = false) {
        DO SOMETHING
    } else {Something else}
```

NOTE: im looking for an IF statement

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery provides the `is` method for checking conditions with regard to a jQuery object. In your case you can check for the `:hover` CSS pseudo class:

```
$('.myBox').is(':hover') === true
```

Havre a look at this demo, try clicking the button (which will alert `true`) and the tabbing to and hitting enter on the button (without the mouse, it will return `false`).

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/LL5JD/

Comment: Tested in Chrome, just tested in FF and it wasn't working... *investigating*.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in jQuery: `uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: hover`

Comment: did you report the bug? because what you provided is exactly what I wanted, gahhhh bugs!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [jQuery Mouse Over](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

```
$(".my_box").mouseover(function(){
    // Mouse over...
});

$(".my_box").mouseout(function(){
    // Mouse left...
});
```

Here is an example, adding a border to an image when hovering over it, and removing it after x amount of time if its not been re-hovered: [See it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/ThLqx/12/)

```
var hover_off = false;
var hover_count = 1000;

$(".my_box").mouseover(function() {
    hover_off = false;
    $(this).addClass('hovering');
});

$(".my_box").mouseout(function() {
    hover_off = true;
    setTimeout(myMouseOut, hover_count);
});

function myMouseOut() {
    if (hover_off) {
        $(".my_box").removeClass('hovering');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's right, $('.myBox').is(':hover') used with jQuery 1.5.1 throws the error, but in my tests only in Opera Browser (11.01):
Uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: hover

**A workaround is using a negated expression**: $('.myBox').is('not(:hover)')
That worked fine while my tests in Opera 11, FF4, IE7, Chrome 5.

Answer (score 1):

Use .hover() http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".myBox").hover(
           function(){
               //DO SOMETHING ON MOUSE ENTER
           },
           function(){
               //DO SOMETHING ON MOUSE LEAVE
           }
 });
```

Comment: Actually this is unbelievably useful. This structure acts as an else clause where ifs cannot be used, for example, when you cannot (coincidentally) use `.hover` with an if because you are struggling with chrome's autocomplete in a pop up login form. If you use `.hover` you will surely get undesired behaviour, instead when you use `$("#foo").mouseout(function(){#The Code},function(){});` you have no problems at all.
Thank you.

Comment: Well said @Luis as for chrome autofill fiascos, someone said that wrapping text inputs in `<form>` tags stop it. I tried it and it works!

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me:

```
var hover = false;
$('.someClass').each(function(i,e){
    hover = !hover ? $(e).is(':hover') : true;
});

if (hover)
    // do something
else
    // do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

use this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/enterleave-events

```
$('.myBox').bind('enter leave',function() {
  // do something, use $(this) to get the object
});
```

Comment: why use a plugin for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events ? they are supported internally with `bind('mouseenter mouseleave', ...`

Answer (score 0):

Act on the [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events.

Or use the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which can handle both of them..

```
$('.myBox').hover(
   function(e){
     //do the mouseenter things here...
   },
   function(e){
     //do the mouseleave things here...
   }
);
```

Example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/ECYD4/

Comment: im trying to create a delay when i hover off of something, so it doesn't close right away, but after maybe 3 seconds, but if i hover off, then hover back on, cancel hover off, so if someone accidentally hovers off, it doesn't close right away.

Comment: @android.nick See the update to my question for an example how to adapt Gaby's code to do what you want. jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/ThLqx/12